# Scene builder doesn't detect classes from other packages

Tags: scenebuilder

Scene builder doesn't detect controller classes from other packages. Anyone knows why? i can type it myself, but i have to type myself the names of every single method or variable name, because it just doesn't see itttt.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.